# Parsing XML into JSON

Tags: java, xml, json, xml-parsing

I have an XML file, like

```
<stock><name>AXL</name><time>19-07</time><price>11.34</price></stock>
<stock><name>AIK</name><time>19-07</time><price>13.54</price></stock>
<stock><name>ALO</name><time>19-07</time><price>16.32</price></stock>
<stock><name>APO</name><time>19-07</time><price>13.56</price></stock>
...............more
```

How can I parse this into JSON structure file?

Comment: What do you mean by "lot of data"?
Also, why caps?!

Comment: Do you want to do that in Javascript OR in JAVA

Comment: both java and javascript are OK. cuz i use jquery to draw line chart with price value. with java, ican parase and generate a jason file, then using jquery ajax function to read it and pass it to draw function.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For a simple solution, I recommend [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org), a Java library for generating and reading JSON with an extension for XML, as it can transform arbitrarily complex XML into JSON with just a few simple lines of code.

**input.xml**

```
<entries>
  <stock><name>AXL</name><time>19-07</time><price>11.34</price></stock>
  <stock><name>AIK</name><time>19-07</time><price>13.54</price></stock>
  <stock><name>ALO</name><time>19-07</time><price>16.32</price></stock>
  <stock><name>APO</name><time>19-07</time><price>13.56</price></stock>
</entries>
```

**The Java Code:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.xml.XmlMapper;

public class Foo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    List entries = xmlMapper.readValue(new File("input.xml"), List.class);

    ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json = jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(entries);
    System.out.println(json);
    // [{"name":"AXL","time":"19-07","price":"11.34"},{"name":"AIK","time":"19-07","price":"13.54"},{"name":"ALO","time":"19-07","price":"16.32"},{"name":"APO","time":"19-07","price":"13.56"}]
  }
}
```

This demo uses [Jackson 1.7.7](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload) (the newer 1.7.8 should also work), [Jackson XML Databind 0.5.3](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-xml-databind/wiki) (not yet compatible with Jackson 1.8), and [Stax2 3.1.1](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/WoodstoxDownload).

Comment: Is that any way without using a third-part stuff?

Comment: @nich No, not really. You will need a library from somewhere in almost any language, although I believe you might be able to avoid using a library iff you used Groovy, which is as much effort as adding a library. Learn about the classpath then download the jars: hint, look at the package names.

Comment: For newer downloads of Jackson, see https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/wiki

Answer (score 0):

http://keithchadwick.wordpress.com/2009/03/14/converting-xml-to-json-with-xsl-part-2/

You haven't specified language... so... I haven't got more specific on it than to think "you already have XML, probably you have access to xsl/xslt":

http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt

http://www.thomasfrank.se/xml_to_json.html