# XML to JSON library

Tags: java, xml, json

Does anyone know of a goood java library for conversion between xml and JSON and back? I am particularly concerned about the attributes i.e.

```
<frank age="30">
```

should be preserved when I serialise to JSON and back. I read up that this is a common problem and age becomes a node underneath the frank node in the back conversion.

I have tried `org.json` which is the quickest way probably. My only problem is that the attributes are not converted back as attributes.

Comment: Share your prior research.  What have you found so far, and why didn't it work for you?  A cursory [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+xml+to+json) turned up [this](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/index.html).

Comment: I vote for http://jackson.codehaus.org/ as well. But, Robert is right, if you search you get many API. I hope you are asking something easy to work with.

Comment: I was using org.json which is the quickest way probably. My only problem is that the attributes are not converted back as attributes. JACKSON seems to be the solution to converting from POJOs to XML/JSON not betweenthe two, unsless I am missing something obvious in the API

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing XML into JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746059/parsing-xml-into-json)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you annotate a `Frank` bean:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

Then use that to marshal to and from that POJO.  You can control what gets created as an attribute vs. a node through annotations.  After you have that, use http://jackson.codehaus.org to convert from the POJO to JSON.  No library is going to know the difference between:

```
<frank age="30" />
```

and

```
<frank>
    <age>30</age>
</frank>
```

when it's coming from

```
{
    frank: {
        age : 30
    }
}
```