# How do I convert a file from one format to any other in java?

Tags: java, json, xml, csv

Is there any java utility or library available that can help me convert file data in CSV, JSON or XML to any other type.

e.g:

```
CSV -> JSON
CSV -> XML
JSON -> CSV
JSON -> XML
XML -> CSV
XML -> JSON
```

Any idea how I can go about this? File size will be a minimum of 100mb so looking at the most process efficient solution.

Comment: Your best option is to decide upon a common file format (or store it in a database) and then write parsers to generate the file in any formats (PS: Even I hate this meaningless downvoting without giving a reason and still couldn't figure out why people do this. Apparently too many people with  ego issues)

Comment: @gonephishing Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FasterXML (Jackson)](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) has the support to read and write to CSV,XML and JSON.

If the format of the data is fixed, it could be read into Java objects, and then output for the different type could be generated by defining [annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations)

Else, a generic solution mentioned by Programmer Bruce at [Parsing XML into JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746059/parsing-xml-into-json) could be used.

Answer (score 1):

Jackson is a good solution for this. See https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

Comment: Heh, same as the one mentioned by Jaiprakash. I think Jackson is an older name for it.